# Concurrent method entry in Spring Controllers

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

In simplest Spring (Boot) applications I observe the following behavior of controllers, say

```
@CrossOrigin
@RestController
public class MyController {
  //...
  @RequestMapping(value = {"/lazy-dog"})
  @ResponseBody
  public Rest lazyDog() {
      //... 
      Thread.sleep(10000);
      //
      return Message("Dog exiting")
  }

  @RequestMapping(value = {"/quick-fox"})
  @ResponseBody
  public Rest quickFox() {
      //...
      return Message("Fox exiting")
  }

}
```

namely: concurrent entry into `lazyDog()` is not allowed (calling it twice from two browser tabs lasts `20sec`), while concurrent execution of `lazyDog()` and `quickFox()` is allowed (as dog waits, fox can quickly execute, say in separate a browser tab).

What should be done to allow for concurrent execution of two or more calls to `lazyDog()`?

Note: I'm currently launching the app via:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
@Override
protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
    return application.sources(Application.class);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you must be testing by opening two tabs in a single browser (or single browser vendor). Can you try simultaneously accessing the URL in different two browsers vendors (say Chrome & IE or Chrome & Firefox etc).

I suspect it most probably could be browser specific implementation of simultaneous HTTP requests sending to same host/url.

Comment: Yes, that was it; thank you. (Concurrent call from Firefox and Chrome to `lazyDog()` executed simultaneously.)

Comment: I ran into the same problem with Chrome. Can you link/provide more info about this behavior? @Madhusudana Reddy Sunnapu

Comment: @Sundeep May be you can refer to "Persistent HTTP Transactions" section of the [following link](http://blog.catchpoint.com/2010/09/17/anatomyhttp/) that says multiple requests can be serviced on the same connection.